# Could not find 'renderReactGridLayout' when integrating react-grid-layout with Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: reactjs, blazor-webassembly, react-grid-layout, blazor-jsinterop

I am facing an issue while trying to integrate "react-grid-layout" in my Blazor WebAssembly App.

I created a JavaScript file called `wwwroot/react-grid-layout.js` with the following code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');

var renderReactGridLayout = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <ReactGridLayout className="layout" cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
                <div key="a" data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }}>A</div>
                <div key="b" data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 }}>B</div>
                <div key="c" data-grid={{ x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }}>C</div>
            </ReactGridLayout>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = renderReactGridLayout;
```

I referenced to this file in `index.html` as follows:

```
<head>
...
    <script type="text/jsx" src="react-grid-layout.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, I created `ReactGridLayout.razor` in the Pages folder as follows:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<div id="grid-layout"></div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
           await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("renderReactGridLayout", new object[] { "#grid-layout" });

        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'renderReactGridLayout' ('renderReactGridLayout' was undefined).
      Error: Could not find 'renderReactGridLayout' ('renderReactGridLayout' was undefined).
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The renderReactGridLayout method is loaded (required) into global variable ReactGridLayout, so assuming that renderReactGridLayout is part of that module's API, then you'd need to fully quality that:

```
await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("ReactGridLayout.renderReactGridLayout", new object[] { "#grid-layout" });
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I get this error: 'Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'ReactGridLayout.renderReactGridLayout' ('ReactGridLayout' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'ReactGridLayout.renderReactGridLayout''